# Prove if it is a linear transformation or not

Tags: linear-transformations

Let $S: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ and $T :\mathbb R\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $T(x)=0$ and $S(x)=x$.  Determine if it is a linear transformation. Also can someone please explain how I should use the axioms of addition and multiplication to prove that it is a linear transformation since I have similar questions to answer.

Comment: Instead of answering this question like everyone else, what exactly do you think is a linear transformation? Why do you think it is called a "linear" transformation?

Comment: T is zero transformation and S is identity transformations.It is damn easy to prove that both are linear.

Answer (score 0):

To show a transform $T$ is linear, for any vectors $x,y$ and scalar $a$, you need to show that $T(a x + y) = a T(x)+T(y)$.

For $T(x) = 0$, $T(a x + y) = 0 = a (0) + (0) = a T(x) + T(y)$ so $T$ is linear. I'll leave you to show that the identity $S$ is also linear.

Comment: Is this correct $ \mathbb S(ax+y) =aS(x)+S(y) $ then $ \mathbb S(ax+y)=x and a a(x)+x=aS(x)+S(y)=x $

Comment: That makes no sense. You have to prove $S(ax+y) = a S(x)+S(y)$.

Answer (score 0):

Try to think about it from both sides. You know $S(x) = x$. Then, what is $S(y)$?  What about $aS(x)+S(y)$? And finally, what is $S(ax+y)$. Hopefully these answers should all be simple, and should lead you in the direction you want to go.

Comment: Hey do you have any video suggestions that would help me on this topic.